# R pick up the starting date and ending date of the Recession period

Tags: python, r, matlab, time-series

I'm trying to plot the Recession Shading periods in R. Consider the following example, recession periods are recognized as 1, and non recession periods are 0.

```
Date           Recession  
1918-09-01     1  
1918-10-01     1  
1918-11-01     1  
1918-12-01     1  
1919-01-01     1  
1919-02-01     1  
1919-03-01     1  
1919-04-01     0  
1919-05-01     0  
1919-06-01     0  
1919-07-01     0  
1919-08-01     0  
1919-09-01     0  
1919-10-01     0  
1919-11-01     0  
1919-12-01     0  
1920-01-01     0  
1920-02-01     1  
1920-03-01     1  
1920-04-01     1  
1920-05-01     1
```

Can anyone help me to pick up the starting date and ending dates of the recession periods? For example:

```
Start                 End
1918-09-01     1919-03-01
1920-02-01     1920-05-01
```

The same question has been asked few years ago, but I think the answer is not able solve this question. see [R Recession Dates Conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739012/r-recession-dates-conversion)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is python tagged? And what did you try? SO is not a code-writing service. Otherwise this is too broad.

Comment: Just think maybe python could be used to do this. I tried to used 'diff(...)' in the recession column, but failed to do that. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect start and end of constant periods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404638/how-to-detect-start-and-end-of-constant-periods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `rleid()` function from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(DF)[, .(min(Date), max(Date)), by = .(rleid(Recession), Recession)][
  Recession == 1, .(Start = V1, End = V2)]
```

> ```
>         Start        End
> 1: 1918-09-01 1919-03-01
> 2: 1920-02-01 1920-05-01
> ```

#### Explanation

The first `data.table` expression finds start and end dates of *all* periods. `rleid()` is a *convenience function for generating a run-length type id column to be used in grouping operations*.

```
data.table(DF)[, .(min(Date), max(Date)), by = .(rleid(Recession), Recession)]
```

> ```
>    rleid Recession         V1         V2
> 1:     1         1 1918-09-01 1919-03-01
> 2:     2         0 1919-04-01 1920-01-01
> 3:     3         1 1920-02-01 1920-05-01
> ```

The second expression picks only the Recession periods and returns the `Start` and `End` dates.

#### Data

```
DF <- readr::read_table(
  "Date           Recession  
  1918-09-01     1  
  1918-10-01     1  
  1918-11-01     1  
  1918-12-01     1  
  1919-01-01     1  
  1919-02-01     1  
  1919-03-01     1  
  1919-04-01     0  
  1919-05-01     0  
  1919-06-01     0  
  1919-07-01     0  
  1919-08-01     0  
  1919-09-01     0  
  1919-10-01     0  
  1919-11-01     0  
  1919-12-01     0  
  1920-01-01     0  
  1920-02-01     1  
  1920-03-01     1  
  1920-04-01     1  
  1920-05-01     1  "
)
```