# How to detect start and end of constant periods?

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to plot recession shading periods in R. Consider the following example, where recession periods are recognized as 1, and non-recession periods are 0.

```
Date           Recession  
1918-09-01     1  
1918-10-01     1  
1918-11-01     1  
1918-12-01     1  
1919-01-01     1  
1919-02-01     1  
1919-03-01     1  
1919-04-01     0  
1919-05-01     0  
1919-06-01     0  
1919-07-01     0  
1919-08-01     0  
1919-09-01     0  
1919-10-01     0  
1919-11-01     0  
1919-12-01     0  
1920-01-01     0  
1920-02-01     1  
1920-03-01     1  
1920-04-01     1  
1920-05-01     1
```

Can anyone help me to pick up the starting dates and ending dates of the recession periods? Expected output:

```
Start                 End
1918-09-01     1919-03-01
1920-02-01     1920-05-01
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21739012/r-recession-dates-conversion) has been asked a few years ago, but I think the answer is not able to solve this question.

Comment: have you looked at `?rle` yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data <- read.csv('recession.csv')

# Add new first and last row to the data, to enable the detection of change
# in the beginning and in the end of the time series.
data <- rbind(c(NA, ifelse(data$Recession[1] == 1, yes = 0, no = NA)),
              data,
              c(NA, ifelse(data$Recession[length(data$Recession)] == 1, 0, NA)))

# Create new data frame containing the start and end of each recession period.
# The periods are detected via built in diff function which calculates 
# differences between all consecutive values in a vector.
recession.periods <- data.frame(
    Start = data$Date[which(diff(data$Recession, lag = 1) == 1) + 1],
    End = data$Date[which(diff(data$Recession, lag = 1) == -1)])
```